# NSURL Unrecognized Selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdata

I have a function in my class:

```
-(void)receiveFileName:(NSNotification *) notification {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
NSString *selectedFileURL = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"selectedFile"];
NSString *fileName = [[selectedFileURL lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:selectedFileURL];
```

}

It receives a file destination url from a table view controller and i need it to produce a fileName string and an NSData but i did some debugging and it gets caught on the NSData part and gives me this error:

-[NSURL getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f507830

When i print the selectedFileURL i get

```
2012-08-14 21:58:01.309 Share Me[4546:907] file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/B87D9131-2E73-4117-9EE8-32EA7E19127D/Documents/mza_9195653795305984944.320x480-75.jpg
```

And when i print the file name i get:

```
2012-08-14 21:58:01.309 Share Me[4546:907] mza_9195653795305984944.320x480-75.jpg
```

I tried using alloc and init but that didn't solve the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selectedFileURL is an NSURL instance, not an NSString - you probably misunderstood the docs of the framework/library you're using. Quick solutions:

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:selectedFileURL];

NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[selectedFileURL path]];
```

etc.

Hint: you could already know that the object was not a string but an URL object as it started with `file://` - that's a special URL scheme for files; NSString instances containing a path don't begin with this prefix, they're of the plain form `/path/to/file.ext`.

Answer (score 0):

verify the string variables (e.g. selectedFileURL) are not `NSURL`s. you can use `isKindOfClass:`, like this:

```
assert([selectedFileURL isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && "not actually a string!");
```

Comment: When i run that i get:
Assertion failed: ([selectedFileURL isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && "not actually a string!"), function -[DataViewController receiveFileName:], file /Users/cristian_rivera/Documents/Share Me/Share Me/DataViewController.m, line 56.

Comment: @Cristian that means `selectedFileURL` not a `NSString` -- it's likely an `NSURL`. objc doesn't do implicit promotions from objc object to objc object, as other languages do. so you might verify `[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"selectedFile"];` is an `NSURL`, then change the variable's type to `NSURL`, then update your conversions. `valueForKey:` (you might have meant `objectForKey:`) returns `id` -- some untyped objc instance which can be assigned to an objc variable without static or dynamic type-checking.